# Can you go back and view the equation you put into the field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

If you have an attribute table column that you populated with values using the field calculator, is there a way to go back and view the calculation you input? This is days later outside so I am no longer in an edit session but I would like to check it again since there are some weird values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, depending on how long ago it was and whether you changed your geoprocessing results settings.
Go to Geoprocessing Drop Down Menu.
Choose Results.
Search the results for Calculate Field.
Click Calculate Field to see the parameters.

Comment: By default, the geoprocessing results are saved for 2 weeks. If you've changed that to a shorter period, you may be out of luck.